Pass in argument of directory for find command to ignore in script
When I call the script (via commandline) I'd like to pass in an optional list of directories for the find command to ignore.  This is what I have but my output includes data from files in the directory that is supposed to be ignored.  This script works as expected without a directory passed in to ignore.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Ensure the script is called with the correct number of arguments
if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <directory> <output_filename> [directories_to_ignore...]"
    exit 1
fi

# Convert the directory to an absolute path
directory=$(realpath "$1")
output_file=$2
shift 2  # Shift the arguments so we can access any ignored directories

# Collect directories to ignore (if provided)
ignore_dirs=()
for dir in "$@"; do
    ignore_dirs+=("-path" "$dir" -prune -o)
done

temp_file=$(mktemp)

# Recursively find all parquet files and save their absolute paths to a temp file
find "$directory" "${ignore_dirs[@]}" -type f -exec file "{}" \; | ug -i -e 'apache parquet' | awk -F: '{print $1}' >> "$temp_file"

# Declare an associative array to store unique MD5s
declare -A md5_dict

# Iterate over each file in the temp file
while IFS= read -r parquet_file; do
    # Extract just the filename from the absolute path
    filename=$(basename "$parquet_file")

    # Search the file for the regex pattern and loop through each match
    matches=$(pqrs cat $parquet_file | sed '/^#\{40,\}/d' | rg -o "md5=\w{32}" | sed 's/md5=//' | sort | uniq)
    
    # Write each unique match on a new line in the output file with the filename prefixed
    while IFS= read -r match; do
        # Extract the actual hash value from the match (remove "md5=")
        hash_value=$(echo "$match")

        # Check if the MD5 is already in the dictionary
        if [[ -z "${md5_dict[$hash_value]}" ]]; then
            # If not in the dictionary, add it and write to the output file
            md5_dict["$hash_value"]="$filename"
            echo "$filename,$match" >> "$output_file"
        fi
    done <<< "$matches"
done < "$temp_file"

# Clean up the temporary file
rm "$temp_file"

echo "Search complete. Results saved to $output_file."

Edited to upload correct version of the script.
UPDATE:
Here is the directory structure I'm working with
.
├── data
│   ├── outputFiles
│   └── parquetFiles
│       ├── 2023-08-06-07-00_1691276460134_127.0.0.1
│       ├── 2023-08-06-07-01_1691276522106_127.0.0.1
│       ├── ignoreThisDir
│       │   ├── 2023-08-06-07-02_1691276582057_127.0.0.1
│       │   └── testFileNottoSearch.txt
│       └── testFiletoSearch.txt
├── db
│   └── docker-compose.yaml
├── dehasher.sh
├── find_pg_files.sh
├── source
└── test.sh

When I run the script I expect it to scrape values out of the two files in data/parquetFiles and ignore the file in data/parquetFiles/ignoreThisDir.  When I run the script and check the output file using ripgrep
rg "2023-08-06-07-02_1691276582057" ouput
there are over 200 matches.

Check out this fine answer over at [so]. You mention directory in the question, but the script speaks of directories; you may want to clarify that. With a single one you're fine w/ $3 and -path "$3" -prune, if you want to exclude several you'll need to be smarter about this.

Thanks for the comments.  I uploaded the wrong script. I'll edit with the correct one.  It's very similar, there's just some minor changes. The one I originally posted was in the middle of being modified.

If I recall correctly, when you use a "list" of OR ed together options, you need to isolate that logic like \( -path dir1 -prune -o -path dir2 -prune -o ... \) which I think you can hard-code into your cmd like find "$directory" \( "${ignore_dirs[@]}" \) -type f ....

@shellter When I do that I get this error:
find: -o: no expression after -o
If I use this:
find "$directory" \( "${ignore_dirs[@]}" -print \) -type f -exec file "{}" \; | ug -i -e 'apache parquet' | awk -F: '{print $1}' >> "$temp_file" there are no errors, but it still includes the directory that I'm trying to ignore.

I always have to experiment (a lot) when doing a find command. Maybe the -prune ONLY goes after the closing \)? and of course, you don't mean that you have \( .... -o \) do you? Of course that will fail. Try \( -path dir1 -o -path dir2  -o -path dir3 \) -prune. Hopefully a real find expert will weigh in.

".... there are over 200 matches."  Yes,  >> "$temp_file" will keep appending each run to your $temp_file.

https://superuser.com/q/1577775/432690

that looks like it produces -path dir1 -prune -o -path dir1 -prune -o -type f -exec ..., which I think is right, since you want the -exec to only apply to the last part, not the pruned directories. You could write that as ( -path dir1 -o -path dir1 ) -prune -o -type f -exec ... too, but it doesn't matter. If it was something like ( -name foo -o -name bar ) -exec ... you'd need the parens to avoid having the action bind only to the last part of the or-list. (remember back-to-back terms are tied with an implicit "and" which binds tighter than "or")

now, you mention ignoring directories with find in the title, so I was only looking at that part. But you could check just the output of find to see if it looks right? (e.g. change the -exec to -print) If it does, then the issue is something else, but I don't know what it is. :) If it doesn't, check again what the actual command line to find ends up being, e.g. with set -x.

Solution:
I changed the loop that iterates through the arguments passed in and puts into an array of ignored directories.  The change that made my script work as expected is below:
ignore_dirs=()
for dir in "$@"; do
    ignore_dirs+=( "-path" $(realpath "$dir") "-prune" "-o" )
done```

When I passed in the ignore directory, I passed in the relative path. The find command seemed to ignore it.  I tested it and it was getting passed into the function properly.  When I pass in the absolute path to the find command it works.

@Kaverni, yes, you're passing the starting directory with the absolute path (you have directory=$(realpath "$1") there), so the paths find processes are absolute too. Anyway, you should quote that $(realpath) command substitution there, since otherwise the output from realpath will be subject to word splitting. But you don't need to quote -path etc., since there's nothing special in them. So ignore_dirs+=( -path "$(realpath "$dir")" -prune -o ).
